# Identifying if the application is terminating because the system is shutting down

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, cocoa, shutdown

I am trying to convert these lines in Objective-C to swift

```
- (NSApplicationTerminateReply)applicationShouldTerminate:(NSApplication*)sender  
{  
   ...  
    NSAppleEventDescriptor* appleEventDesc = [[NSAppleEventManager sharedAppleEventManager] currentAppleEvent];  
    NSAppleEventDescriptor* whyDesc = [appleEventDesc attributeDescriptorForKeyword:kEventParamReason];  
    OSType why = [whyDesc typeCodeValue];  
    if (why==kAEShutDown || why==kAERestart || why==kAEReallyLogOut)
```

they will detect if the app is terminating due to the system shutting down.

I am unable to convert this line

```
if (why==kAEShutDown || why==kAERestart || why==kAEReallyLogOut)
```

I guessed something like

```
    let codeValue = whyDescription?.typeCodeValue

if ((codeValue == AEKeyword(kAEShutDown)) ||
    (codeValue == AEKeyword(kAERestart)) ||
    (codeValue == AEKeyword(kAEReallyLogOut))) {
```

Is this correct?

or should it be

```
if ((codeValue == OSType(kAEShutDown)) ||
    (codeValue == OSType(kAERestart)) ||
    (codeValue == OSType(kAEReallyLogOut))) {
```

Xcode is compiling it fine, but I am not sure if `kAEShutDown`, `kAERestart`, and `kAEReallyLogOut` are `AEKeywords that can be used there.

I could find no documentation on that, as expected.

Comment: Both `AEKeyword` and `OSType` are just aliases for `FourCharCode`. It doesn't matter which one you use.

Comment: ahhh, thanks and please make this comment an answer, so I can accept.

Comment: This might be useful too: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31332210/341994

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `AEKeyword` and `OSType` are a `typealias` to `FourCharCode`. Technically, they are the same type, therefore it does not matter which you use.

However, since `typeCodeValue` is declared as `OSType`, then `OSType` is the logical choice.

Also, it seems the constants are already declared as `OSType`, therefore there should not be any reason to cast them.

Comment: @SpaceDog Actually, what error you get when you don't use the `OSType(...)`? The constants should already be `OSType`.

Comment: I was getting an error because I was typing them as `.kAEShutdown`. Without the dot them compile fine. Thanks.